# How to send email in Outlook on behalf of a Delegate?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, ms-access-2007, outlook-2007

I'm writing a VBA script that will fire off emails to our customers.  I've made similar systems before, but the difference here is that these emails will use a generic From field (so the recipient only sees our company's name and not the individual sending it).  This is easy to do manually.

Currently, I'm playing around with the SendUsingAccount with generic [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869311.aspx).  But I can't figure out how to use that code since it's not an actual account on this machine per se. I just have delegate access to it.

So, can someone show me how to send email on behalf of someone else using VBA?

(Alternatively, I do have the username and password to the account. So, if I need to log into that account to send the email, I can do that too)

Comment: Do you mean on behalf of, or do you mean to send as someone else?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know there was a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206695%28v=office.12%29.aspx). You should have delegate access to the mailbox/profile on whose behalf you want to send.

### Example:

```
Sub SendEmailOnBehalf()
  Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem

  Set msg = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  With msg
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Jimmy's boss' name"
    .Subject = "Email from someone else"
    .Body = "Hello" & vbNewLine 
  End With
End Sub
```

The email would say `From Jimmy Pena on behalf of Jimmy's Boss` in the `From:` field.

Comment: Great. It really was as simple as I thought.

Comment: I tested this by sending to myself.  Actually,  the email only has the name of the delegate, not the actual sender.  So in your example, I think it would just say "Jimmy's Boss".

Comment: I get these emails also (and meeting requests), I usually see `x on behalf of y`. I am using Outlook 2003.