# Change SenderEmailAddress in Access vba

Tags: email, ms-access, vba

I was wondering if it is possible to change the `.SenderEmailAddress` Property within Access VBA. Whenever i try to change this property i receive this error:

Compile error:

Can't assign to read-only property

I'm trying to send emails from a central generic email I have setup to receive feedback from a customer. I do not want to be receiving emails from the recipient to my personal email/email on the Client. The generic email that I have setup contains the same domain tag as my personal.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of the listed question. I need to find a way to change the From address, not just change the overlay name that displays. When a user reply's, it needs to get sent to the generic email. Not the access-client email that sent it.

Also, here is my code

```
Dim myMail      As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myOutlApp   As Outlook.Application

Set myOutlApp = New Outlook.Application
Set myMail = myOutlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With myMail

    ' trying to set the from address
    .SenderEmailAddress = "info@generic.com"

    .To = "customer@othercompany.com"

    .Subject = "Hey"

    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

    .HTMLBody = "<!DOCTYPE html>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<html><head><body>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<h1><u>This is an example header line</u></h1>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<h2><u>This is an example header 2 line</u></h2>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<table>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<tr><td>Element 1</td><td>" & strElement1 & "</td></tr>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<tr><td>Element 2</td><td>" & strElement2 & "</td></tr>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</table>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</body></html>"

    .Display

End With

Set myMail = Nothing
Set myOutlApp = Nothing`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email in Outlook on behalf of a Delegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513869/how-to-send-email-in-outlook-on-behalf-of-a-delegate)

Comment: @Chance Finley can you post the code that you are using ? it will be better to understand.

Comment: @Comintern that is an interesting solution, but still would not fix the replying aspect of the email. Changing the name is nice, but it would still come from my email directly, therefore they would reply and the email would come to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CDO Object email instead of mapi object, sample code below, copied from [link](http://access-excel.tips/send-email-vba-cdo-olmailitem/)

```
Public Sub SendEmail()
  Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1
  Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2
  Const cdoAnonymous = 0
  Const cdoBasic = 1     ' Use basic (clear-text) authentication
  Const cdoNTLM = 2  'NTLM  ' Use NTLM authentication
  Dim imsg As Object
  Dim iconf As Object
  Dim flds As Object
  Dim schema As String

  Set imsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
  Set iconf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
  Set flds = iconf.Fields

  ' send one copy with SMTP server (with autentication)
  schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
  flds.Item(schema & "sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort
  flds.Item(schema & "smtpserver") = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
  flds.Item(schema & "smtpserverport") = 465
  flds.Item(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
  flds.Item(schema & "sendusername") = "scammera1@yahoo.com.hk"
  flds.Item(schema & "sendpassword") = "password"
  flds.Item(schema & "smtpusessl") = True
  flds.Update

 With imsg
    .From = "scammera1@yahoo.com.hk"   'Should be same as sendusername
    .To = "scammera1@yahoo.com.hk,terethan@hotmail.com"
    '.Bcc = "test@email.com"
    '.Cc = "test@email.com"
    .Subject = "This is a subject"
    .HTMLBody = "<h1>This is a test message<h1>"        
    'TextBody = "This is a test message"         
    .Sender = "This is the sender"       
    '.Organization = "My Company"        
    '.ReplyTo = "address@mycompany.com"        
    '.AddAttachment "c:\temp\readme.txt"                
     .Send     
   End With
 Set .Configuration = iconf  
 Set iconf = Nothing     
 Set imsg = Nothing     
 Set flds = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this solution later today. Thanks for the reply

Comment: This is a good answer, it led me to a much simpler method of using CDO.Message without requiring authentication. Something that is noteworthy, if you want to send to emails outside of the domain, you need to change some exchange settings.Thanks for the reply. See settings [here](http://terenceluk.blogspot.com/2011/10/unable-to-relay-mail-to-external-domain.html)