# Run-time error '-2147221233(8004010f)': object not found - Access Database

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

I'm building a scheduling database for my office, and have it mostly finished. The last step is sending an automated meeting out for the schedule created each day. This email MUST come from a secondary email account/calendar shared by all members of my team. The code below runs just fine on my personal computer, but will not run on others even though they have access to the same email and calendar.

The error I get is this:

> run-time error '-2147221233(8004010f)': The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.

The line it's screwing up on is this: `Set OLFolder = OLNamespace.Folders.Item("name@address.office.com")`

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub sendacdcsched_Click()
'sends an email with a calendar appointment for the facility schedule.

    DoCmd.Save 'saves the record first

    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim Outlookmessage As Object
    Dim scheduleACDC As String
    Dim OLNamespace As Object
    Dim OLFolder As Object

    scheduleACDC = "Schedule for ACDC for " & Me.schedDate.Value

    'Create Instance of Outlook
    On Error Resume Next

    Set OutlookApp = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application") 'Handles if Outlook is already open
    Err.Clear
    If OutlookApp Is Nothing Then Set OutlookApp = CreateObject(Class:="Outlook.Application") 'If not, open Outlook
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OLNamespace = OutlookApp.getnamespace("MAPI")
    Set OLFolder = OLNamespace.Folders.Item("name@address.office.com")

    'Create a new email message
    Set Outlookmessage = OLFolder.items.Add(1)

    'Create Outlook email with attachment
    On Error Resume Next
    With Outlookmessage
        .meetingstatus = 1 'makes it a meeting so you can add recipients
        .start = Me.schedDate & " 8:00:00 AM"
        .duration = 240 'in minutes
        .To = ""  'Insert all emails addresses to be sent to here'
        .subject = "ACDC"  'email subject line'
        .Body = scheduleACDC
        .Display 'displays email before you send it. If you wish to send without seeing it displayed use .send'
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't cause this error, but you haven't declared the variable type of OLFolder

Comment: Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513869/how-to-send-email-in-outlook-on-behalf-of-a-delegate or try using CDO and FROM property. http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/EMail.aspx

Comment: For some reason FROM doesn't work. Neither does SentOnBehalfOfName. I'm looking into CDO property now, since I'm not very familiar with it.